# Is it possible to make cv2.matchTemplate faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to make my code faster. I'm comparing if an image has a water with 3000 watermark logos. It takes about 10 min until every picture has been compared and it can be said to a probability of 90% that the picture has no watermark. Because 10 min are very long is there any possibility to shorten this process to maybe 1 min?

This is my code:

```
img_gray = loadimagein_gray(im1)
count = 0
for X in path:
    template = cv2.imread(X)
    found = False
    w, h = template.shape[:-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold =0.85
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    if found == False:
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):  # Switch columns and rows
            cv2.rectangle(img_gray, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255)
```

Comment: You could try using the Transparent API (`UMat`) to take advantage of OpenCL implementation. You could parallelize it (multiple processes or threads), or even pipeline (`imread` in one threadpool, analyze in another). Maybe it can still be accurate enough to do at reduced resolution? Are the templates tightly cropped? | Of course, you can always acquire more powerful CPU, or scale it across multiple machines...

Comment: How can i parallelize this process in this case?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You have N images and M watermarks and you want to see if any images contain any of the watermarks, correct? What is N and what is M?

Comment: img_gray is N/images and template/X is M/watermarks